# Electron spawn enonent exception

Tags: javascript, bash, electron

I m trying to run some sh from my electron app, I tried two approaches but I m still strugling with the enoent exception that occurs when the script is unreachable and that what I cant grasp in my code

first my working tree is like below

```
electron_app
           +
           +   app
           +   +   batch
           +   +   +   -process.js
           +   +   +   -run_source.sh
           +   other_folders
```

**process.js  Exec Version**

```
    const { execFile } = require('child_process');

    cmd = './run_source.sh';

    console.log([source, m3u8_source, folder])

    const child = execFile(cmd, [source, m3u8_source, folder]);


    console.log(child);

    child.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('stderr: <' + err + '>');
    });

    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        let pid;
        if (data.search("pid=") !== -1) pid = data.substring(data.search("pid="), data.lenght);
        console.log(pid)
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: <' + data + '>');
    });

    child.on('close', function (code) {
        if (code == 0)
            console.log('child process complete.');
        else
            console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);

    });
```

**process.js spawn version**

```
    const process = require('child_process'); 

    var child = process.spawn(cmd,[source,m3u8_source,folder]);

    //the same code above
```

My console logs the following

> stderr:  Error: spawn ./run_source.sh ENOENT
>   child process exited with code -2

I have already chmoded +x my sh script

What to do ??

Answer (score 0):

**Finally**

```
const path = require('path');
const run_source = path.join(__dirname, 'run_source.sh');
```

getting the correct path of the sh like this fixed the issue